# jest.spyOn is not working with destructured functions

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs, destructuring

Why jest.spyOn is not working with destructured functions that are destructured out site the test?

the following test will fail:

```
export const Funcs = {
  foo: () => {
    return 'foo';
  }
};

const { foo } = Funcs;

test('should pass', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Funcs, 'foo');
  foo();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

however, it will work if we move the destructuration inside the test:

```
test('should pass', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Funcs, 'foo');
  const { foo } = Funcs;
  foo();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I don't think it has to do with inside or outside the test. Looks like just a basic ordering issue here. The first example wouldn't work either if the destructuring was done as the first line in `'should pass'`. Would you expect that to work as well?

Comment: correct, its to do with ordering, i get it now :)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `jest.spyOn(Funcs, 'foo');`, the Funcs object gets modified to have a new `foo` property. Your first code example is accessing Funcs.foo before you've mocked it, and so the `const foo` is referring to the real function. Your second code example is accessing Funcs.foo after you've mocked, so you're pointing to the mock function.

If you strip away the use of jest and the destructuring, here's an illustration of what you're doing. Accessing before modifying:

```js
const example = {
  value: 1
}
const val = example.value;
example.value = 2;
console.log(val);
```

Modifying before accessing:

```js
const example = {
  value: 1
}
example.value = 2;
const val = example.value;
console.log(val);
```

Comment: This is correct. It's such a shame we can't use nice destructured requires() if spying is needed on any of the imported functions.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - I was writing tests for my Express.js controllers which utilised a few helper functions, which were all imported using deconstruction and an `index.js` file. When trying to write these tests I had trouble intercepting the original functions to mock them. I originally settled on a default import for these helper functions which allowed me to `jest.spyOn` them easily and worked, but visually I prefer deconstructing imports.

However I was playing around with it today and I got it working with deconstruction by setting all my spies before importing my controller file. This way I'm successfully intercepting and mocking the original function before it gets imported into the controller file. So this works:

```
  const utilities = require("../utilities");
  const axiosInstanceSpy = jest.spyOn(utilities, "pchAxiosInstance");
  const createPCHObjectSpy = jest.spyOn(utilities, "createPCHObject");
  const pchController = require("./pchController");
```

But this wont:

```
  const utilities = require("../utilities");
  const pchController = require("./pchController");
  const axiosInstanceSpy = jest.spyOn(utilities, "pchAxiosInstance");
  const createPCHObjectSpy = jest.spyOn(utilities, "createPCHObject");
```